# CSS - Units of measurement and screen resolution: what's reference pixel, anyway?

Tags: css, screen, pixel, measurement

Hi, there! I was reading the W3C spec about Units of measurement (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#reference-pixel) and the fact is that I didn't understand what is a **reference pixel**. Can you guys explain it to me, or point me to another reference or explanation that's easier to understand. Also I'm not sure if I really understand the other things about Units and Measurements ha ha. Really, that seems too hard.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference pixel is an attempt to standardize what "pixel" means in web development. The reason that this matters is because the physical measurement of a pixel can vary greatly depending on the pixel depth of the display.

For example, old CRT monitors had 72 pixels per inch, whereas an iPhone 7+ has 401 pixels per inch. So a literal measurement of 100px would be 1.39 inches on the CRT monitor and 0.25 inches on the iPhone.

This article also has a pretty good explanation that helped me understand it better.

> A List Apart, "*[A Pixel Identity Crisis](https://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis/)*" by Scott Kellum. January 17, 2012
>
> "The w3c currently defines the reference pixel as the standard for all
>   pixel-based measurements. Now, instead of every pixel-based
>   measurement being based on a hardware pixel it is based on an optical
>   reference unit that might be twice the size of a hardware pixel. This
>   new pixel should look exactly the same in all viewing situations..."
>
> "When using a phone that you held close, a reference pixel will be
>   smaller on the screen than a projection you view from a distance. If
>   the viewer holds their phone up so it is side-by-side with the
>   projection, the pixel sizes should look identical no matter the
>   resolution or pixel density the devices have. When implemented
>   properly, this new standard will provide unprecedented stability
>   across all designs on all platforms no matter the pixel density or
>   viewing distance."